# How to design API for getting collections objects?

Tags: api, design-patterns

I have a lot of different lists. Objects of lists have fields that are objects too.

When I do request to the server, I get a response that sees like(people):

```
[
   {
      id: 1,
      fistName: "Steve",
      lastName: "Jobs",
      companyId: 1
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      fistName: "Warren",
      lastName: "Buffett",
      companyId: 2
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      fistName: "Bill",
      lastName: "Gates",
      companyId: 3
   }
]
```

Here companyId is ID of another object. The company, for example:

```
[
   {
      id: 1,
      title: "Apple",
      cityId: 1
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      title: "Berkshire Hathaway",
      cityId: 2
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      title: "Microsoft",
      cityId: 3
   },
]
```

Here cityId is ID of objects cities etc.

When I get a list of people, I need to know the titles of companies and cities.

How can I design my API for it?

1. One request that will send all the information. For example:

```
{
   data: [], //Array of people
   payloads: {
      companies: [], //Array of companies
      cities: []     //Array of cities
   }
}
```

2. Several requests each of which will send its information. Then I have to make several requests from client to server, each time requesting additional information.

Answer (score 0):

In similar scenario I have used a concept that we called "InterfaceAPI". You should create a new api that has the task to resolve a backend level your problem.  So, in this case new output object is more or less

```js
GET baseurl/companiesInterface
[
   {
      id: 1,
      fistName: "Steve",
      lastName: "Jobs",
      companyId: 1,
      companyName: "Apple",
      cityName: "xxx"
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      fistName: "Warren",
      lastName: "Buffett",
      companyId: 2,
      companyName: "xxx",
      cityName: "xxx"
   },
   {
      id: 3,
      fistName: "Bill",
      lastName: "Gates",
      companyId: 3,
      companyName: "xxx",
      cityName: "xxx"
   }
]

GET baseurl/companiesInterface/1
   {
      id: 1,
      fistName: "Steve",
      lastName: "Jobs",
      companyId: 1,
      companyName: "Apple",
      cityName: "xxx"
   }
```